# Spring Boot Kotlin: No qualifying bean of type <REPO> available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin

It is a single package Spring boot application.

What I tried:

1- Add **scanBasePackages** on the Main class

2- Add @Autowired before all dependencies injection in constructors

3- Different versions of spring boot and kotlin,

4- Provide UserServise manually,

5- Set custom Qualifier name for everything,

6- Spend 2 days to read related topics in stackoverflow

---

Error:

```
Parameter 0 of constructor in <Dir>.service.appuser.AppUserServiceImpl required a bean of type '<Dir>.repository.AppUserRepository' that could not be found.
    
    
    Action:
    
    Consider defining a bean of type '<Dir>.repository.AppUserRepository' in your configuration.

    ---->>>>> <TIME>  WARN 89358 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: 
    ---->>>>> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'appUserController' defined in file 
    ---->>>>> [<PackageDir>/build/classes/kotlin/main/<Dir>/controller/AppUserController.class]: 
    ---->>>>> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'appUserServiceImpl' defined in file [<PackageDir>/build/classes/kotlin/main/<Dir>/service/appuser/AppUserServiceImpl.class]: 
    ---->>>>> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: No qualifying bean of type '<Dir>.repository.AppUserRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

---

Main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication(// I Tried to specified scanBasePackages
    exclude = [
        SecurityAutoConfiguration::class,
    ],
)
class SecurityRestApplication

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<SecurityRestApplication>(*args)
}
```

Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("$BASE_API_PATH/app_user")
class AppUserController(
    private val appUserService: AppUserService,
) {

    @PostMapping("/v1/login")
    fun loginV1(@RequestBody loginDto: LoginDto): ResponseEntity<LoginResponseDto?> {
        val loginResponse: LoginResponseDto? = appUserService.login(loginDto)

        return if (loginResponse != null) {
            ResponseEntity(loginResponse, HttpStatus.OK)
        } else {
            ResponseEntity(null, HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN)
        }
    }
    
    ...    
}
```

AppUserService interface:

```
interface AppUserService {

    fun getAppUserById(id: Long): Optional<AppUser>

    fun getAppUserByUsername(username: String): Optional<AppUser>

    fun getAllAppUsers(): Collection<AppUser>

    ...

}
```

AppUserServiceImpl:

```
@Service
class AppUserServiceImpl(
    private val appUserRepository: AppUserRepository,
    private val passwordEncoder: PasswordEncoder,
    private val authenticationManager: AuthenticationManager,
): UserService {

    override fun getAppUserById(id: Long): Optional<User> {
        LOGGER.debug("Getting user={}", id)
        return Optional.ofNullable(appUserRepository.findByIdOrNull(id))
    }

    override fun getAppUserByUsername(username: String): Optional<User> {
        LOGGER.debug("Getting user by username={}", username)
        return appUserRepository.findOneByUsername(username)
    }

    ...
}
```

AppUserRepo:

```
@Repository
interface AppUserRepository : JpaRepository<AppUser, Long> {
    fun findOneByUsername(username: String?): Optional<AppUser>

}
```

Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(
    indexes = [
     Index(name = "username_index", columnList = "username", unique = true),
    ],
)
data class AppUser(

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    val id: Long? = null,

    @Column(unique = true)
    var username: String,

    var firstName: String? = null,

    var lastName: String,

    var passwordHash: String,

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    var appUserRole: AppUserRole,
)
```

---

Full Log Error:

```
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:<port>', transport: 'socket'

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.1.5)

<TIME>  INFO 89358 --- [  restartedMain] g.s.s.SecurityRestApplicationKt          : Starting SecurityRestApplicationKt using Java 21.0.1 with PID 89358 (<PackageDir>/build/classes/kotlin/main started by <NAME> in <PackageDir>)
<TIME>  INFO 89358 --- [  restartedMain] g.s.s.SecurityRestApplicationKt          : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
<TIME>  INFO 89358 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
<TIME>  INFO 89358 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): <port> (http)
<TIME>  INFO 89358 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
<TIME>  INFO 89358 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.15]
<TIME>  INFO 89358 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
<TIME>  INFO 89358 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2878 ms
<TIME> DEBUG 89358 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.s.ServletContextInitializerBeans : Mapping filters: addForwardedPortHeader urls=[/*] order=-200, characterEncodingFilter urls=[/*] order=-2147483648, formContentFilter urls=[/*] order=-9900, requestContextFilter urls=[/*] order=-105
<TIME> DEBUG 89358 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.s.ServletContextInitializerBeans : Mapping servlets: dispatcherServlet urls=[/], h2Console urls=[/h2-console/*]


---->>>>> <TIME>  WARN 89358 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'appUserController' defined in file [<PackageDir>/build/classes/kotlin/main/<Dir>/controller/AppUserController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'appUserServiceImpl' defined in file [<PackageDir>/build/classes/kotlin/main/<Dir>/service/appuser/AppUserServiceImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: No qualifying bean of type '<Dir>.repository.AppUserRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}


<TIME>  INFO 89358 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
<TIME>  INFO 89358 --- [  restartedMain] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
<TIME> ERROR 89358 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in <Dir>.service.appuser.AppUserServiceImpl required a bean of type '<Dir>.repository.AppUserRepository' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type '<Dir>.repository.AppUserRepository' in your configuration.

Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:<Port>', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 0
```

---

Every thing you request in comments:

Database: H2

App properties:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:./storage/database
spring.flyway.locations=classpath:./storage/
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=<pass>

spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.open-in-view=true
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
```

Project package:
[image]

UserRepository in Spring beans:

[image]

- I changed UserController to AppUserController
- I changed UserService to AppUserService
- I changed UserServiceImpl to AppUserServiceImpl
- I changed UserRepository to AppUserRepository
- I changed User to AppUser

Comment: Do you use an Oracle database?

Comment: @Twistleton, No it's H2

Comment: User is a reserved keyword at Oracle.  Maybe check how it is with H2.

Comment: @Twistleton yes, but I tries with different names also I changed all other classes names like UserRepository to AppUserRepository, line number 4 in What I tried

Comment: The UserRepository is also in a subdirectory of your application, so that the repository is found during the component scan?

Comment: @Twistleton, Yes, I add 2 pictures it in my question, and also when I set custom name for @Repository(name = "newName") UserRepository I see It when using @Qualifier("newName")

Comment: Spring Boot 3 request at least Java 17.  But you have certainly thought of that. Otherwise, everything actually looks very good.

Comment: @Twistleton Yes I used Java 21 and also tried with 20, 
And I have another application with same structure which works fine, but I have n o idea why it's happening to this project :))

Comment: Where is your AppUserRepository-implementing class?

Comment: @k314159 Isn't the implementation automatically provided by Spring JPA?

Comment: I'm intrigued, have you already tried recreating minimal working project with identical structure?

Comment: @JanItor ,yes I have another projects with same structure, and they works fine, same packages, same libraries, the only thing I applied here is spring security, but I tried to disable it bud it's didn't work.

Comment: @ShahriyarAghajani One more idea: have you ever tried using the CrudRepository instead of the JpaRepository?

Comment: @Twistleton, Yes, I tried :)), I started another project with other libraries and now i'm working on the one one, I totally disappointed with this project

Comment: @Twistleton btw thank you for caring, now I am working on some flork of this repo: https://github.com/Shahriyar13/spring-boot-kotlin/tree/master/rest-jwt-jpa